# LDAP3 search when Active Directory accounts expire

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

I want to specify an [LDAP3](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) search against an Active Directory server which returns when the PW of an account expires.

```
server = Server(server_name, port=636, use_ssl=True, get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, user='{}\\{}'.format(domain_name, user_name), password=password, authentication=NTLM, auto_bind=True)

 conn.search(
            search_base=f'OU={root_ou},OU={sub_ou},OU={org_ou},DC={domain_name},DC={domain_suffix}',
            # search_filter='(objectClass=person)',

            # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-accountexpires
            search_filter='(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.159)',
            # search_scope='SUBTREE',
            attributes=[ALL_ATTRIBUTES, ALL_OPERATIONAL_ATTRIBUTES]
)
```

Can I specify the search filter in a way [so that it returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-accountexpires):

> The date when the account expires. This value represents the number of
> 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC). A value of 0 or
> 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (9223372036854775807) indicates that the account
> never expires.

I would like to see the actual value as a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give you the complete solution in Python, since I'm not a Python developer, but I can point you in the right direction.

The `accountExpires` attribute tells you when the *account* expires, not the password.

If you want the password expiry, it's a bit harder. You first have to find out the maximum allowed password age on your domain. To do that, look at the [`maxPwdAge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-maxpwdage) attribute at the root of the domain. You can bind to the root of the domain just like you can any user, e.g. `LDAP://DC={domain_name},DC={domain_suffix}`

Once you have that, you can look at the [`pwdLastSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-pwdlastset) attribute on the user account, then do that math to figure out if it has been longer than the maximum allowed age. If the value is `0`, then the user must change their password at next logon.

You must also check if the user has a password that never expires. That flag is part of the [`userAccountControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-useraccountcontrol) attribute, which is a bit flag. You're looking for the `ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD` flag, which has a hex value of `0x10000`. You can use Python's [bitwise AND](https://realpython.com/python-bitwise-operators/#bitwise-and) operator `&`:

```
if userAccountControl & 0x10000:
     # Password does not expire
```

If that flag is set, then the value of `pwdLastSet` is irrelevant.